# Start 4 programs on startup in Linux Mint via terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, linux-mint, c

I'm working on a project and I hope you can help me solve a problem.

I have four programs that are written in C. They have been compiled using `gcc` and they work as they should. Because the four programs are drivers for some devices, I need to start them again if the PC resets for any reason, or if the power supply is lost.

In the programs I have some parts where I am printing some statuses, and for the moment I start the programs using a console.

How can I start the programs on startup in Linux Mint?

Is it possible on startup to activate four consoles and with the consoles so start the program? If not do I have to transfer the output of the programs in file? (Four devices is connected to the PC via four serial ports.)

Answer (score 3):

You could include execution of your programs in `/etc/rc.local` file for them to be started automatically. Furthermore, you'd need to redirect the output to meaningful files so that you can inspect them later. In other words, in `/etc/rc.local` add something like this before the `exit 0` line:

```
/path/to/program/program1 >> /path/to/output/file/program1.output
/path/to/program/program2 >> /path/to/output/file/program2.output
/path/to/program/program3 >> /path/to/output/file/program3.output
/path/to/program/program4 >> /path/to/output/file/program4.output
```

Comment: if i print some statuses whit printf in my program can i view that in my output file?

Comment: ok i solved this!

Comment: YES, your output file will contain those stutuses