# Run root script or command as root in startup application in linux mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, networkmanager, networkcard

I have a wireless adapter that used to work in Linux mint 16 (dwa 171) after installing drivers for it. Now it won't work the same way anymore since I upgraded to linux mint 17.

I've found the only way to make it work properly is to run the command `sudo service network-manager restart` I already tried putting this command in rc.local, rc2.local and rc3.local with no real luck. I want this command to run automatically right after login in with startup application program. Please tell me how to.

Comment: You could add it to your `$HOME/.bash_profile` (assuming that you are using bash as your default shell. If you are using a different shell, then you could add it to its configuration file (run a `man` on the shell that you use to identify the correct file). If it is an application that you need to have start this, then if it has a start up script, then you could add it to the start section of that script.

Comment: Yes, I'm using bash as my default shell. But I don't really know how to add it to my bash. If you could answer it with a proper solution with the steps and it works I might choose your answer.

Comment: Probably better to add it in /etc/rc.local before the exit 0 line. Someone else posted a similar problem [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87236/start-4-programs-on-startup-in-linux-mint-via-terminal)

Comment: @Warwick Yes, I know I have to add it before the exit 0 line. I'm not that of much of a noob.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put it in rc.local because that runs at boot time, not AFTER you log in.

First, carefully edit your /etc/sudoers file from within the /etc dir:

```
sudo visudo
```

And as the last entry in the section that starts with:

```
#Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
```

add the following:

```
%sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

For ease of use, I would add your script to a path that's already specified as secure for sudo users, as specified at the top of the sudoers file. For mine, I created my script in my home dir, then ran

```
chmod +x /my/file
```

then went to /usr/bin and ran

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/my/script nameOfScriptForMySymbolicLink
```

then I went to my Startup Apps window (location will differ for your distro), clicked on 'Add' and gave it a descriptive name, then put

```
/usr/bin/nameOfScriptForMySymbolicLink
```

in the command line, closed out, rebooted and logged in and it works a charm.

Comment: It should be noted that a script in a user's home directory which can be executed as root using sudo is a security risk. The user (or any program run by them) could change that script at will and execute any command as root. You may not care, but I thought I'd state it for the record. Better: Create that script in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin or /usr/opt/bin and make it owned by root, `rwxr-xr-x`.

Answer (score -1):

One way might be to simply use crontab like so:

```
crontab -e
```

and then put this at the bottom:

```
@reboot /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Remember to set this up while being logged in as root.

Comment: The question asks specifically how to run the task right after log-in. This runs at system boot up.

Comment: The result is pretty much the same, i assumed that he wants the manager to be restarted right after boot, as it would make no sense to wait until he has actually logged in.